# Bootable disks gone after installing ubunto on another drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, hard-drive

Installation or failed installation caused both of my ssd to become unbootable.

I just got my 1tb nvme drive and installed fresh windows on that. I decided to try out linux and installed ubuntu on my old 250gb sata ssd. I used a usb stick to install the os.

Once i tried to install i chose the option to erase the old 250gb drive and install ubuntu on it. I got an error after it tried to install, right before you select a region on a map. I don't remember what error war thrown(might have something to do with partitions) but i could only ignore or cancel and it was suggesting a reboot before continuing. Once i hit restart it froze and after some minutes i decided to hit reset key. From there i could no longer boot to any disk because there was no drives to boot from according to my bios. Entering bios showed no bootable drives. I decided to carry on with installation and i could chose between 1tb and 250gb drive in installation. I chose the 250gb drive and installed successfully. In ubunto i can see my 1tb drive but i can't boot from it, my bios can only see the 250gb drive now.

Is there a way to make my drive visible to my bios again so i can boot from it or do i have to reinstall windows on it?
I guess my second question is how this happened. Why did failed installation make all my drives disappear and why does installing ubuntu on one drive affect other drives? Making it unbootable and recognizable by bios.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XM44pqpFzY/

Comment: If you're still thinking about "booting drives" in an era of UEFI mode installations you're doing it wrong.

Comment: What do you mean? It should be possible to install different OS on different drives, no?

Comment: Yes, of course it should and it is. The problem is you thinking about the old BIOS mode that boots from different drives' MBRs. In UEFI mode the system boots from the ESP and only one is required and only one is typically used no matter the amount of physical drives and the actual location of systems partitions.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi <- That this as a general reference for dual-booting and adapt it to your specific system.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair <- Please try the 2nd option in the same live session you used to install . Do NOT apply any repair but instead use the "create a bootinfo summary option" and then [edit] the question and post the result here.

Comment: Added the result

Comment: 1st problem: Windows 7 - Obsolete and dangerous. Using it in 2022 is dumb AF. 2nd problem: Windows 7 installed in Legacy mode, then Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode. The link above already mentions this situation.

Comment: This win 7 throws me off because i don't use win 7, i have been on win 10 for years now. It says windows 7 on nvme0n1p2, so my guess is it's on the new 1tb drive. Which is impossible because i got it today and installed win11 on it. Win11 was also installed on the old drive as of 1 week ago (new mobo).

Comment: Windows 11 it CAN'T be for the simple reason that unlike previous versions it DOESN'T support Legacy/"BIOS" mode.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding as i referred to UEFI as bios. win11 ran on old drive, win11 ran on new drive. After failed ubuntu installation, when entering UEFI there were no drive to to select to boot from. After installing ubuntu i can only see the old drive with ubuntu on it. The new nvme with win11 on it is not visible in UEFI. Do you think running boot-repair will solve this issue?

Comment: You haven't read the Q&A, have you? If you did WHY are you still talking about "drives"? And no, Boot Repair *may* have misidentified the Windows version (hard to believe because that would be a first) but there's no doubt Windows was installed in Legacy mode (so it CAN'T be Win11) and Ubuntu properly in UEFI mode. Dual-boot can't work this way unless by changing mode in UEFI. Ubuntu as it is should boot without problems though.

Comment: Turned on CSM and windows boot option appeared, but was unable to boot from it. I tried to reinstall windows on the 1tb drive but now get "Inaccessible Boot Device Error" I think when ubuntu installer failed it did some good damage. What is the fix for that? Will reformat disk help? I hope its not bricked

Comment: Windows in UEFI mode requires gpt partitioning. So if drive is MBR, it will either not install or convert entire drive to gpt totally erasing it. Make sure you have any data you want to keep well backed up. BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I was unable to fix/bring back the main disk (disk 0). When the installation of Ubuntu failed it also for some reason f-ed over disk 0 while trying to wipe and install on disk 1. I was unable to reinstall win11 on disk 0 as it threw  "Inaccessible Boot Device" Error.

I was able to fix this with windows installer and running diskpart in command prompt with a clean command. No UEFI setting needed to be changed, dual-boot works fine now. Running win11 on disk 0 and Ubuntu on disk 1 as planned.

Thanks to the people in the comments for helping with troubleshooting.